# Deploying WAR to Fuse ESB get 'FileNotFoundException: URL [bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/]'

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-servicemix

Any help would be gratefully received...

Maven Spring Roo project, JPA2 combined with CXF archetype simple Web Service application.

After deploying to Fuse (Servicemix 4.4.1) as a WAR (Fuse converts this into a bundle), when activating (osgi:start nnn) get the following error..

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/**

Seems to be when Springs component scan starts..

**app-context.xml** contains

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.bookstore.app" />`

Apologies for the extended stack trace, but thought it may prove useful...

```
21:28:07,365 | INFO  | l Console Thread | XmlBeanDefinitionReader          | 248 - mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war - 0.0.0 | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]
21:28:07,457 | WARN  | l Console Thread | hMatchingResourcePatternResolver | 248 - mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war - 0.0.0 | Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundle://248.0:1/com/bookstore/app/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:204)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:168)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:528)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:349)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:267)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1227)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:204)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:204)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)[248:mvn_com.bookstore_bookstore-ws_1.0-SNAPSHOT_war:0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$1.call(HttpServiceContext.java:168)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$1.call(HttpServiceContext.java:164)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.addEventListener(HttpServiceContext.java:161)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl.addEventListener(JettyServerImpl.java:235)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Started.addEventListener(ServerControllerImpl.java:276)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl.addEventListener(ServerControllerImpl.java:127)[160:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.registerEventListener(HttpServiceStarted.java:286)[158:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.registerEventListener(HttpServiceProxy.java:133)[158:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:276)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:561)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:170)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:155)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$HttpServiceListener.serviceChanged(WebAppPublisher.java:119)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.setService(ReplaceableService.java:114)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.access$100(ReplaceableService.java:28)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService$CollectionListener.serviceAdded(ReplaceableService.java:183)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection$Tracker.addingService(ServiceCollection.java:181)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)[karaf.jar:2.2.2-fuse-04-06]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.2.2-fuse-04-06]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)[karaf.jar:2.2.2-fuse-04-06]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)[karaf.jar:2.2.2-fuse-04-06]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)[karaf.jar:2.2.2-fuse-04-06]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceCollection.onStart(ServiceCollection.java:139)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ReplaceableService.onStart(ReplaceableService.java:146)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle$Stopped.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:121)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycle.start(AbstractLifecycle.java:49)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:81)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.doPublish(WebXmlObserver.java:304)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebXmlObserver.addingEntries(WebXmlObserver.java:153)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.register(BundleWatcher.java:186)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher.access$000(BundleWatcher.java:45)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.extender.BundleWatcher$1.bundleChanged(BundleWatcher.java:127)[163:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:795)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:717)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:597)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3781)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1792)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:927)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:914)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9-fuse-05-06.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:29)[19:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)[19:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:240)[36:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.2.fuse-04-06]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_29]
```

Comment: wow!..look at this.....we need some more..

Comment: Guys, if someone has just joined SO, show some kindness rather than instant down vote.   The question isn't vague, so it doesn't warrant this.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot - but it looks like some Spring is trying to scan for the bundle cache but has got confused as to the bundle's original location.

In your Fuse configuration, try switching from Felix to Equinox, in Karaf it's in `etc/config.properties` and the property is `karaf.framework` - should be virtually the same in Fuse ESB.

Comment: I tried switching to equinox but I had the same error.  I do wonder if this is a red herring as the exception is logged as a WARN.  I get further errors with NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.  I originally assumed this was due to the headline exception above.  This is the first time I've tried to deploy a WAR as a bundle and using Servicemix so will go back to the Fuse/Servicemix documentation.  The console suggests all the correct required JARs are on the class path but it does sound like a class loading issue.  Thanks again for your time and answer.

Comment: Ah, you may need to explicitly add extra package imports to your bundle, especially if these are for classes only defined in XML - add the org.springframework.context to your WAR's imports and any others you seen defined in app-context.xml

Comment: Great, thanks!  That did it.  I found by adding the manifest\addClasspath attribute to the maven-war-plugin configuration solved the issue.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html

Comment: Can you mark this questions as resolved, as you got a solution from earcam

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page,

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/ops4j/Pax+Web+Extender+-+War+-+Examples

`<context:component-scan base-package="*" />` is currently not supported by OSGI environment. Make sure that you make use of `<context:annotation-config />` and define all your components as beans in your application context.